# Division Operator Sublime Text

Tags: javascript, operators, division, sublimetext3

I am a javascript student, just started. I use Sublime Text 3 and I can't figure out why the division operator (/) is not working for me, when I try the same code in jsfiddle it works perfectly. It is a very very vey simple task.

something as dumb as below:

```
<script>
var a;
var b;
var c;
a=parseInt(prompt("Enter first number"));
b=parseInt(prompt("Enter second number"));
c=parseInt(prompt("Enter third number"));
var total=(a+b+c);
var avg=total/3;
alert(a +", "+ b +", "+ c + " | Average = "+avg);
</script>
```

Why is the division in this line **var avg=total/3;** not being recognised??
Is there a different way to divide?

Thank you in advance and happy new year!

Marcelo O.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working", and what does the editor have to do with it?

Comment: `console.log(avg);` after assignment -what are the results?

Comment: What do you mean by "not being recognised"? Do you mean that the `/` operator isn't higlighted in the same color as the `+` operator?

Comment: As you're starting out with Sublime, keep this in mind: Sublime Text (at least versions 2 and 3)'s default syntax highlighting **sucks**. The default highlighters are intentionally minimalist for performance. Don't worry, you will find many other bugs and inconsistencies. `=]`

Comment: Hi @DaveNewton frankly I do not know what the editor has to to with it, but it was not highlighting the (/) operator in red as with all the others, and when I tried to run the code in chrome this code line would not run. The code is properly written since it works in jsfiddle. The error was randomly solved after restarting Sublime multiple times and opening other codes in it, it still does not highlight the (/) but the code runs smoothly. Thank you for the efforts and happy new year.

Comment: @KLVTZ I tried the console.log, but it would not show anything in Chrome, anyway the error was randomly solved after restarting Sublime multiple times and opening other codes in it, it still does not highlight the (/) but the code runs smoothly. Thank you for the tip!

Comment: @p.s.w.g that is exactly what I meant with the extra that the whole line wasn't running due to this. The problem desappeared after restarting ST3 many times. Thanks!

Comment: @FabrícioMatté I am totally new on this, so I just followed some reviews... Do you have any advise on a good editor for MAC OS? Thank you!

Comment: Sublime is not really a bad editor, that is, it has thousands of plugins which makes your life easier -- the first thing you should do after installing Sublime is to install [package control](https://sublime.wbond.net/), then you can easily install plugins with it. But yes, it takes a while to make Sublime the way you want. As for a suggestion, [JetBrains WebStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/products.html#javascript) is a very (if not the most) advanced JavaScript IDE at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, try checking the `value` and `typeof` the variable `total` to ensure it is an integer.

You should also add a radix to your parseInt functions, as this may be causing `a`, `b`, or `c`  to be `nAn` [see mdn for example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

I would also recommend installing a static analysis tool for sublime, something like [Sublime-JSHint](https://github.com/victorporof/Sublime-JSHint) You will find it extremely useful for catching syntax errors.

Comment: Hi Daveee, problem has been solved, thank you for the help and tips, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Why do you say it is not running? If it works in your fiddle, which you say it does, it runs just fine. Sublime Text 3 is *NOT* a Javascript runtime environment.

You need to add more details as to what you mean when you say "not working".

Comment: Hi TjonS, I am really sorry I lacked information in my question, code was running in here www.jsfiddle.com but the specific line I pointed would not run when I would run the html file in the browser. It was fixed after many restarts... Thank you very much!